# How do I connect a button on Visual Studio 2022 in WinForms application?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Nuget package (System.Data.SqlClient-4.8.3) in Visual Studio 2022. How do I add a button to run my C# code as an on-click for a WinForms GUI? I'm using the Entity-Framework .NET 6.0.

Comment: See: [How to handle a control event (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the documentation is unclear for Visual Studio 2022. See solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This youtube video is a little more comprehensive for where to find the "ToolBox", what to look for in the toolbox, and how to manipulate click actions for events:

[Adding and Writing Code on Button using Visual Studio 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kcy9iG2PT7Y)

If your ToolBox is not showing, then go to views and toggle it on.